# How to display dynamically the count of number of characters below the TextField (Inline)

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a textbox as shown below,which will dynamically show the count of characters as user types
[UI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsb9i.png)
(React JS)

Comment: Can you please provide code of what you have tried so far?  What is currently working and not currently working?

Comment: <TextField
        id="abc"
        label="DoorName"
        className={classes.textField}
        value={values.name}
        onChange={handleChange('name')}
        margin="normal"
      />

  const handleChange = name => event => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
  };


I will add Validations also,but I want Inline text just below the field which will tell user that "how many characters you have already typed"

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```js
const max = 15;

class Application extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: {
      value: '',
      count: 0,
    },
  };
  
  handleChange = (e) => {
    if(e.target.value.length > max) return;
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: {value: e.target.value, count: e.target.value.length }});
  }
  
  render(){
    const { text } = this.state;
    return(
      <div style={{width: 'fit-content'}}>
        <input name="text" value={text.value} onChange={this.handleChange} onFocus={this.handleChange} />
        <div>
          <span style={{float: 'left'}}>Max {max} characters</span>
          <span style={{float: 'right'}}>{text.count} / {max}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: You've understood the question wrong, she wants to count the number of letters in the input field, not remaining ones.

Answer (score 1):

This is one with React Hook:

https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-platform-tb4jr 
(Here I am using `textarea` value property)

UPDATE:

This one is not resetting the counter. Need to handle all keyboard events.
[https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-framework-c158w][1]

Comment: You count never resets, it just adds and keeps on adding.

Comment: For length, here it is fixed: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-platform-tb4jr